# How to Scale the bitmap to Support mulitscreen in canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

i'm creating a game app for this i want to scale the bitmap image size according to screen densities for this i used this logic where i   multiplied scale value to bitmap height and width  but its not scaling properly some devices it's too large so any solution that for this .
//canvas bitmap image

```
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

 canvas.drawBitmap(statebitmap, null, new RectF(pauseX, pauseY, pause.getWidth()*scale, pause.getHeight()*scale), null);
```